# Is it possible to PCBA without a Gerber file & BOM

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly, gerber, bom

I have a designer designing the Gerber and generating the BOM from a logic design.I have half the information like the circuit drawings  and circuit working. He says he will complete the gerber and BOM much after i need to deliver the project. Hence i'm in a hurry.

Comment: The gerber file is created from the layout.  Once the layout is done, it only takes a little while (minutes) to make the gerber files - the design program does that almost automatically.  So, most likely it isn't just that the gerber files aren't finished.  The real problem is that the layout isn't finished.  No layout, no PCB.

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange. Please be more specific: what exactly is the question here?

Comment: When you are saying "circuit working", what's the physical embodiment of the said circuit?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the PCB itself manufactured without the Gerber files, nor the solder paste stencil(s), so you will have nothing to assemble until some time after receiving the Gerber files.

PCBA can use the centroid file and BOM but those are generated after layout is complete, more or less instantly along with the Gerber files if the EDA software has been fed the BOM information up front, otherwise the BOM may take longer (the parts can be procured while the bare PCBs are being manufactured).

Answer (score 0):

The gerber is the design for the PCBA, I can't think of a more efficient route.

maybe you can get faster results by paying more?

Answer (score -2):

You can get some perfboard and make one or two by hand.